# Migrate failing in laravel 4.2.*

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to write a simple REST API for laravel 4.2. Here is my code:
This is the command to generate two tables:

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --table=users --create
php artisan migrate:make create_urls_table --table=urls --create
```

Then I added this code in `up` section of `create_users_table.php`:

```
 $table->increments('id');
 $table->string('username')->unique();
 $table->string('password');
 $table->timestamps();
```

I added this code in `up` section of `create_urls_table.php`:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->string('url');
$table->string('description');
$table->timestamps();
```

My db configurations are like this:

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'read_it_later',
            'username'  => '<username>',
            'password'  => '<password>',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

Then I added this to `UserTableSeeder.php` in `seeds` folder in `database` folder:

```
<?php

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete();

        User::create(array(
            'username' => 'firstuser',
            'password' => Hash::make('first_password')
        ));

        User::create(array(
            'username' => 'seconduser',
            'password' => Hash::make('second_password')
        ));
    }

}
```

Then I uncommented `$this->call('UserTableSeeder')` in `DatabaseSeeder.php` file.
Then I ran this command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

And I got the following error:

```
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

Do you really wish to run this command? y
Migration table created successfully.



  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'read_it_later.users' doesn't exist (SQL: alter table `users` add `id` int unsigned not   
  null auto_increment primary key, add `username` varchar(255) not null, add `password` varchar(255) not null, add `created_at` timestamp default 0   
  not null, add `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null)                                                                                            






  [PDOException]                                                                                 
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'read_it_later.users' doesn't exist  



migrate [--bench[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--force] [--path[="..."]] [--package[="..."]] [--pretend] [--seed]
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You should check your create_users_table.php. For some reason the users table is being altered and not created. Since it doesn't exist that might be the case.

Comment: Make sure you are using the `Schema:create` method and not `Schema::table` within your migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that I was using wrong command to generate migration tables.
I used the following commands:

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --create=users
php artisan migrate:make create_urls_table --create=urls
```

Then I added my code to those files and tried these commands:

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan db:seed
```

And it worked